# How to show Warnings and Errors message of PHP in NetBeans?

Tags: php, netbeans

for example

```
<?php
$fail = 1/0; 
?>
```

following warning shows in browser

```
Warning: Division by zero in C:\myserver\ProjectPhp\index.php on line 2
```

i want see this warning in the NetBeans

is it possible? and how?

Comment: I assume you mean `1/0`

Answer (score 0):

It's running time error. No launching -- no error message like this. Netbeans can highlight some probably erros like 'undefined variable', but it wrong often (for me : ) ).

You could see errors inside NetBeans if you will customize to launch launching using CLI. After doing this you can run php files inside NetBeans window. So, you will see errors in NetBeans :^ )